# Wordpress: Add item to frontend menu

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I am developing a wordpress plugin and want to add a menu link (frontend, not admin menu!).

I found the `wp_nav_menu_items` filter, but it doesn't change anything in the menu.

Current code looks like this:

```
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items','add_field');

function add_field($nav){
    return $nav."<li>TEST</li>";
}
```

Do I have to "execute" this filter? If yes, how?

Comment: Place this in end of your plugin file

Comment: It is at the end of my plugin file, but still not working.

Comment: To check this is working place it in your `function.php`(for only test purpose

Comment: @DhinjuDivakaran as long as the plugin is active it shouldn't make a difference. He would just be overriding the function in that case.

Comment: @DhinjuDivakaran @ham-sandwich Yep, I get an php error that I can't redeclare the function. If I just add the `add_filter`, nothing happens.

Comment: Filter seems to be added correctly (I can find it in $wp_filter), but isn't executed...